# flashdevelop vs flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I just started making games and I decided for my next project to use either flashdevelop or  flex builder. Reason being is because you can embed just about everything and for licensing purposes and it recommended the the game is compiled into one file. flex sdk is good with that type of stuff.

As of right now I decided to use flashdevelop. but recently it's been kicking my behind. First I wasnt able to use ui class (e.i. buttons, and textboxes) probably because of something stupid I did. Now for some reason I can not compile my applications. When I compile, nothing happens, no errors, no nothing. below is a screenshot of what happens when I compile.

Yes i installed debugger and yes I installed sdk

[image]

So now I was thinking about just going with flex builder. Not sure which one is more easier to assemble and use. But I do know the flex builder community is bigger, and they have a much better documentation. I am good with actionscript, but I am not so good with using flex.

My ultimate question is...

Which one is easier to assemble
which one is easier to use
which one is BETTER overall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as not compiling goes, looks like it compiled just fine.
I don't know what you're expecting to see from the code other than the "Hello"
to see that open up your output window (under View)

Whether you use flex or flashdevelop, you end up using the same compiler.

Like Adam, I find flashdevelop easier to use than flex, but that's because I've used it more (flex trial expired and FD didn't)

And plus I'm fast with FD, like really fast :)

Try some of the shortcuts:

- to create getter and setter or
  generate function press 'ctrl shift ~' and PRESTO
- or for a for loop or for each loop type in the first few
  letters and press 'ctrl B'
- to find   instances of any string in code you
  can do F3 and shift F3, whereas F4
  will find the object or function
  declaration(even in separate files)
- FD also adds a lot of the classes as
  needed (sometimes I have to do it manually)
- and the latest version lets
  you generate classes which extend
  another class easier.

I'm sure that flax does most of this as-well, but when you're already used to this then switching slows you down.

I had the same issues when I started working with FD. What it boils down to is that flex has a bunch of libraries that it's using that FD doesn't unless you link to them, and sometimes even then.

But once you start compiling your libraries and assets into SWCs you will be able to compile them through Flash and Flex. Which can be handy (like when you're working with other developers)

FD doesn't have a profiler, but this has not prompted me to stop using it. When I need some debugging and trace isn't enough I add the demonsters debugger class: http://www.monsterdebugger.com/ it's pretty powerful, but you still can't step through your code.
** Update - Flash Develop has had a profiler for a few versions now, It's good for watching memory use, but I still end up using monster debugger a lot. You can use debug in Flash Develop as-well and step through your code.**

FD doesn't have the UI that flex does, and for developing mxml it is a bit more tedious, but at pure as3, I find FD is all I need. Well than and Flash to create my SWCs

Comment: I was able to figure it out. It was because  my output window was closed up so I wasnt seeing the output like I was use to seeing at the bottom. petty mistake. But thanks for helping out

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of it is personal preference, and what you have previously used. Some people do have strong opinions though.

Personally I like FlashDevelop, but only because I am use to it, and can get things done a lot faster e.g. setting up projects, workflow, shortcuts etc. But I am sure If I forced myself to only use FlashBuilder ([formally FlexBuilder](http://theflashblog.com/?p=993)) that I would soon come to grips with its nuances.

Here are a few of **my** points for either side:

### FlashDevelop:

- I like how FlashDevelop is so simple,
  where as Flash Builder is rather
  bulky.
- FlashDevelop is totally free, where Flash Builder actually cost quite a bit.

### Flash Builder:

- Built on Eclipse, so has a massive community, tons of plug-ins etc.
- Source control intergrated into the IDE (very important in large projects).

Also might want to check out this article on [ActionScript Editors](http://accelermedia.com/content/flash-actionscript-editor-flex-builder-vs-flashdevelop).

Comment: I would like to use flashdevelop, but I keep running into issues. I guess i can open a new post for that and hope I can get it resolved

Comment: You would probably run into a lot more issues trying to use Flash Builder! It is a lot more complicated to use for first time uses.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but in case someone finds it, here is an interesting thing I've noticed:

I am using pixel fonts in my project, and by default Flash Player blurs part of it (it is a known problem). One solution is to use a bitmap text (some kind of custom class) and the other is to use [Text Renderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextRenderer.html) with some of its related elements to force Flash to render the font correctly. When compiling under the same version of Flex SDK in Flash Builder 4+ the font rendered correctly. But when I compiled with Flash Develop (latest version) the text was really ugly, with missing pixels at random places. It might be caused by the fact that Flash Develop or Flash Builder are sending some hidden arguments to the compiler which either make it work/break.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long running question that has been repeated a few times. Review this question and see if it answers yours.

[Web-based Game Development: Flex Builder or Flash CS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369558/web-based-game-development-flex-builder-or-flash-cs3)

Comment: This questions is about FlashBuilder (FlexBuilder) vs FlashDevelop, and the question you linked is about FlashBuilder vs Flash Authoring. Still has some relivant points though.

Comment: yes the article linked is flash vs flex. I would like to make comparison to flash develop and flex builder